# How do i return to the main URL root in codeception?

Tags: php, automated-tests, codeception

I have my config file set up so that calling:

```
$I->amOnPage('page');
```

Puts me on

```
http://example.com/page
```

Then I call

```
$I->amOnUrl('http://someothersite/');
```

And I run a few methods there.
Now I want to return back to my site. But if I call

```
$I->amOnPage('anotherpage');
```

It tries to put me on someothersite/anotherpage instead of example.com/anotherpage.

How can i set the root URL back to the default in the config file? I know I could call $I->amOnURL() again, but then I have to hard code the root URL somewhere - maybe in a constant - but how can I have it revert back to the default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the original URL as set in the suite YML like this:

```
$config = \Codeception\Configuration::suiteSettings("suiteName", \Codeception\Configuration::config());
var_dump($config);
```

Where "suiteName" is something like "acceptance".